# Redirect user to PayPal checkout page after sending email

Tags: php, javascript, paypal

I have an order form where a user gives some input about a product and when s/he submits the form s/he will receive an email which contains product specification.

Basically the website provide Logo designing services.

Here products are : 3 Logo Mockups, 5 Logo Mockups, 7 Logo Mockups and 10 Logo Mockups, not any tangible product like(other shopping cart offers).

Now, I have created a PayPal **Buy Now** button using paypal account for that product and want to send an email(which contain product specification that s/he had already filled before click to **Buy Now** button) to the customer as well as redirecting them to the appropriate product checkout page generated by PayPal.

Paypal **Buy Now** button code is:

```
<form id="logo-design-paypal-form" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="46J7HLDHY7TBE">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Logo Design">
            Logo Design</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><select name="os0">
        <option value="3 Logo Mockups">3 Logo Mockups $50.00</option>
        <option value="5 Logo Mockups">5 Logo Mockups $120.00</option>
        <option value="7 Logo Mockups">7 Logo Mockups $350.00</option>
        <option value="10 Logo Mockups">10 Logo Mockups $650.00</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
```

Comment: This question isn't very clear, and the tags make it even more confusing.  You have created a PayPal button using what?  Does it use a server-side PHP shopping cart, or does it use PayPal's shopping cart framework?  You could add a GET parameter to the email form, something like ?paypal, to redirect to PP after the email is sent — but PayPal already sends an email when a cart is purchased.  Please clarify.

Comment: PayPal Buy Now button using paypal account

Comment: Please clarify the question. What do you have now, what do you want it to do, what's stopping you from doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, earlier, you created a form with a normal submit button. If a user enters all the input and clicks submit, you would send him an email. Right now, you replaced the normal button with a PayPal submit button and you wants that PayPal button to invoke the sending email function just like the old button. If that's what you want to do, you can try this way:

```
<div id="paypal_button">
    // wrap your encrypted paypal button in a div
</div>

// PayPal button is actually a form so you can make a script like the following

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("div#paypal_button > form").submit(function() {

        // Call your sending email function here (maybe by using Ajax)

    });
</script>
```

**EDIT**: if you don't want to bind onclick event to the PayPal button itself, I think you should use this Ajax [plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to submit your original form (i.e. don't use normal submit because the user would be redirected to the page in action attribute and it'd be more difficult to achieve what you want).

```
<form id="original_form" action="somePage">
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>

<div id="paypal_button" style="display:none">
    // wrap your encrypted paypal button in a HIDDEN div
</div>

<script type="text/javascrip">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // submit your original form to send the email and redirect the user on success
        $('#original_form').ajaxForm({
            success: function() { 
               $("div#paypal_button > form").submit();
            }     
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes you got my point but my email data contains lot of text with at least 2 to 4 attachments and css, so I used normal form submit to a send.php and it works excellent. I just want to redirect the user to his selected package paypal checkout page right after sending email and nothing else...
Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer but I still think it's better to use the 1st approach as the code looks cleaner. ^^